# Get selected checkboxes on document.ready()

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am having list of checkboxes as follows:

```
<div class="quaterly-dates-list">
<label>
<input type="checkbox" value="Q1 2012">
<span>Q1 2012 </span>
</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" value="Q2 2012">
<span>Q2 2012 </span>
</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" value="Q3 2012">
<span>Q3 2012 </span>
</label>
</div>
```

I need selected checkboxes on document.ready event.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: `$("input:checked")` can work...

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var checkboxes = $("div.quaterly-dates-list :checkbox:checked").map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
});
```

This will give you an array of values for the checked boxes in div `quaterly-dates-list`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selectedCheckboxes = $( "input:checked" );
});
```

For more information, check out [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Please give your checkboxes names so that they are usable; so they can be serialized .. etc:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Q1" value="Q1 2012">
<input type="checkbox" name="Q2" value="Q2 2012">
<input type="checkbox" name="Q3" value="Q3 2012">
```

To get the names and values of those checked use:

```
 $(function() {
     var ckArr = $('div.quaterly-dates-list').find(':checkbox:checked')
     .map(function(i,v) { return { v.name: v.value }; }).get();
 });
```

To get just the values of the checked use:

```
 $(function() {
     var ckArr = $('div.quaterly-dates-list').find(':checkbox:checked')
     .map(function(i,v) { return this.value; }).get();
 });
```